# How to style all but last row in a table without attributing it explicitly?

Tags: css

I'm doing something like this:

```
$("#accountsTable")
  .append(getHeadersFromJson(json))
  .append(getRowsFromJson(json));
$("#accountsTable")
  .css("border", "3px solid black");
$("#accountsTable th")
  .css("border-bottom", "3px solid black");
$("#accountsTable td")
  .css("border-bottom", "1px solid black");
```

It looks good except I just noticed that the last row has two *border-bottom*'s - one thin for *TD* and one think for *TABLE*. I can live with that. However, the perfectionist in me cries a little.

Is there a CSS way to remove the last line style without actually attributing it with a name, id, style etc. during creation?

Comment: Downvoter: care to explain what can be improved here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tr:last-of-type td {
    border: none;
}
```

or

```
$("#accountsTable tr:last-of-type td").css({border:"none"});
```

Comment: This style (*last-of-type*) was new to me. How does it compare to *last-child*?

Comment: :last-child refers to an element's position in the parent among siblings of any type, :last-of-type refers to a specific type of element. :last-of-type is safer. It's sort of hard to explain, this does it well http://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-nth-child-and-nth-of-type/

Answer (score 3):

```
td:last-child { border: none; }
```

I think this should do it.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution is reducing the `th` border to 2px and then using `border-top` instead for each `td`.

Answer (score 1):

Just set the following on your table:

```
border-collapse: collapse;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the bottom border from your table:

```
border-bottom: none
```

or remove the border for td in the last row:

```
tr:last-child td{
    border-bottom: none;
}
```

Comment: The first one won't do. Looks ugly. The second suggestion is OK, though.

Answer (score 1):

Try the :not selector

[https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:not](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/%3anot)

```
td:not(:last-child) {
 border: 3px solid black;
}
```

and if you're worried about browser support, check out http://selectivizr.com/